# SERIAL fields / Auto increment

Tags: sql, postgresql

The task indicated this:

Create a table named automagic with the following fields:

An id field is an auto-incrementing serial field.
A name field that allows up to 32 characters but no more This field is required.
A height field is a floating-point number that is required.
And my code was:

```
CREATE TABLE automatic (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    name CHAR (32), 
    height numeric);
```

However, the self-rater answered this Expecting an INSERT without a height to fail, it did not fail.

After that, I tried this

```
CREATE TABLE automatic (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
    name varchar(32) not null, 
    height float not null);
```

And got

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "auto_increment"
> LINE 1: CREATE TABLE automagic (id int not null auto_increment prima...\
>
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 41

Comment: Postgres doesn't support `auto_increment`.  So, it is not appropriate in a `create table`.  You seem to know the answer (at least one answer) because it is in the title of the question.

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) did you find that syntax?

Comment: It worked now CREATE TABLE automagic (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name varchar(32), height float not null
);

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE automagic (
  id int NOT NULL,
  name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  height float NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE automagic_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE automagic_id_seq OWNED BY automagic.id;

ALTER TABLE ONLY automagic ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('automagic_id_seq'::regclass);
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @a_horse_with_no_name, this is better:

```
CREATE TABLE automagic (
  id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  height float NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I've edited my answer, but feel free to write your own answer and I'll remove mine.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this:

```
CREATE TABLE automagic (
id SERIAL,
name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
height FLOAT NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over the previously posted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE automagic (
id SERIAL primary key,
name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
height FLOAT NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

CREATE TABLE automagic (
id serial,
name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
height float  NOT NULL
);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The true is NOT NULL never mentioned in lectures.
I finally did it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE automagic (
 id SERIAL, 
 name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
 height FLOAT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You must put ; at the end of the query
Try this

```
CREATE TABLE automagic ( id SERIAL, name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, height FLOAT NOT NULL);
```

Comment: The queries in the question all have semi-colons.